# K-Means on dataset in which first column is User Name(String) & Second Column is ID(Integer) to do clustering of ID

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to apply K-Means on dataset in which first column is User Name(String) & Second Column is some ID(Integer) considering to do clustering of ID in Same cluster.

**Sample Data**

User Name        Associated ID

1. rajan.kumar         2134
2. rajan.kumar         2134
3. rajan.kumar         2194
4. mano.singh          5196
5. mano.singh          2134
6. mano.singh          2194

Can we apply K-Means in Python to grouping the above dataset considering group as ID because i searched many article have no solution based on string.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clustering problem.

You seem to be looking for SQL `GROUP_BY`.